# SSAS - Could Dimenstion attribute value calculated based on another dimension attribute value?

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimension

Usually the dimension attribute is used in Cube for filter or slice cube. So the dimension attribute value should be set by user, when user access cube via excel. Is it possible to dynamically calculate dimension attribute value? For example: 
Dim_A.Attri1 has value: a, b
Dim_B.Attri2 has value: 0, 1

Here if user set Dim_A.Attri1 as value: a and Dim_B.Attri2 has value 0, the cube measure shows number 100, if user set Dim_A.Attri1 as value: b and Dim_B.Attri2 has value 1, the cube measure shows number 200. The both combinations are correct.

But user has to set 2 dimension attributes. Is it possible to set in cube Dim_B.Attri2 value calculated based on Dim_A.Attri1, so that:
When Dim_A.Attri1 = a, then Dim_B.Attri2 = 0
When Dim_A.Attri1 = b, then Dim_B.Attri2 = 1

User doesn't need to set two dimensions. I didn't find where can program MDX in dimension attribute property, only in DefautMember. But it doesn't work for this purpose. Could some one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Jane

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to pre-calculate the measure values at ETL stage or define a CASE statement if you are using a View as opposed to doing it in MDX at run time.

I guess it all depends on how the values rollup.